# How to change the color of md-navbar?

Tags: angular-material

I need to change the color of the Angular Material md-navbar. At present I see only white background option. How can we change the color of the md-navbar?

Comment: You can use md-theme, but this affect all the element color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdNavBar), there doesn't appear to be a way to assign a class or id to the `md-nav-bar`, as with other AM directives, to which you can apply styling.

However, if you inspect the element in the console you will see this:

[image]

So you could just use CSS:

```
md-nav-bar .md-nav-bar {
  background: yellow;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/EyrjvA)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but on another property. When I inspect my navbar, it says the following:

.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
    background: #1976d2;
    color: white;
}

but trying to change the background of .mat-toolbar.mat-primary doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: @WouterVanherck Your question is related to Angular Material 2. If you would like to create a new question I will try to answer it. :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to this question, I'm fairly new to Angular 2 and keep mismatching things. However, me and my colleague are currently editting the template which  seems to work (not flqless), rather than overriding the css.